# How do I correctly use tryCatch() and ignore 404 errors in this rvest function?

Tags: r, web-scraping, dplyr, rvest

I've written this function for scraping lyrics:

```
songscrape <- function(x) {
  url <- paste0("https://www.azlyrics.com/", substring(x, 1, 1),"/",x, ".html")
  artist <- x
  
  SongsListScrapper <- function(x) { 
    page <- x
    songs <- page %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/a") %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      as.data.frame()
    
    
    chart <- cbind(songs)
    names(chart) <- c("Songs")
    chart <- as.tibble(chart)
    return(chart)
  }
  
  SongsList <- map_df(url, SongsListScrapper)
  SongsList
  
  SongsList %<>%
    mutate(
      Songs = as.character(Songs) 
      ,Songs = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", Songs) 
      ,Songs = tolower(Songs) 
      ,Songs = gsub(" ", "", Songs) 
    )
  
  SongsList$Songs
  
  #Scrape Lyrics 
  
  wipe_html <- function(str_html) { 
    gsub("<.*?>", "", str_html)
  }
  
  lyrics2 <- c()
  albums2 <- c()
  number <- 1
  
  for(i in seq_along(SongsList$Songs)) { 
    for_url_name <- SongsList$Songs[i]
    
    
    #clean name
    for_url_name <- tolower(gsub("[[:punct:]]\\s", "", for_url_name))
    #create url
    paste_url <- paste0("https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/", artist,"/", for_url_name, ".html")
    tryCatch( { 
    #open connection to url 
    for_html_code <-read_html(paste_url)
    for_lyrics <- html_node(for_html_code, xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]")
    for_albums <- html_node(for_html_code, xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[11]/div[1]/b")
    error = function(e){NA}
    })
     for_lyrics <- wipe_html(for_lyrics)
    for_albums <- wipe_html(for_albums)
    lyrics2[number] <- for_lyrics
    albums2[number] <- for_albums
    
    number <- number +1
    
    show(paste0(for_url_name, " Scrape Complete!", "[",i,"/",nrow(SongsList),"]"))
    
    Sys.sleep(10)
  }
  
  songs2 <- cbind(lyrics2, albums2) %>% as.data.frame()
  songs2$albums2 <-  gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", songs2$albums2)
  
  return(songs2)
}
```

You will notice that I have used `tryCatch()` in the code (shown also below) because I realized that on some edge-cases, the URL would not match and stop the function midway:

```
tryCatch( { 
    #open connection to url 
    for_html_code <-read_html(paste_url)
    for_lyrics <- html_node(for_html_code, xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]")
    for_albums <- html_node(for_html_code, xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[11]/div[1]/b")
    error = function(e){NA}
    })
```

However, I *still* get this error and the code stops functioning, instead of ignoring the error and moving on:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.
In addition: Warning message:
In for (i in seq_len(n)) { :
```

What am I doing wrong and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Your `tryCatch()` is not correct - check your braces - the error handling needs to be outside the expression.

Comment: @27ϕ9 Do you mean like this: https://pastebin.com/3qKWSKGA (I've also added a comma after the closing brace, is that correct?)

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by User @27ϕ9, the `trcyCatch()` was not used correctly. The error handling needed to be outside the closing brace:

```
tryCatch( { 
    #open connection to url 
    for_html_code <-read_html(paste_url)
    for_lyrics <- html_node(for_html_code, xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]")
    for_albums <- html_node(for_html_code, xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[11]/div[1]/b")
}, error = function(e){NA}
    )
```

For more information, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r) answer here.